# Holiday System - Show all team holidays to a manager

Tags: list-view, filter

I'm currently building an automated holiday system for the company intranet. The issue I'm having is trying to find a way of managers to view their team members holidays in a calendar list.

The only way I can think of right now is to create multiple pages with different views (filters) and restrict the pages to the relevant manager, but obviously this is a long-winded and probably unnecessary method.

Can anyone help with a quicker and dynamic way of doing this?
Note: I am new to SharePoint, starting from around 2-3 weeks ago.

Comment: id say one calendar per team and turn on item-level permissions in the advanced settings, and give the manager the manage list permission.

Comment: @Mike Your idea did give me an insight into another solution: 
1) Add a line manager column to the calendar list
2) In SPD, update the line manager column in the calendar to the line manager of the leave request
3) Filter the view so Line Manager = [Me]

In theory, this should allow the view to filter any items that have the value of the current user in the Line Manager column. I don't have time to finish this now, but will complete tomorrow and confirm if it works.

Comment: that will work, but please note that is not completely restrictive. Views and filters are not bound by security, and some people are okay with that because it's hard from an end-user's perspective to get access to documents hidden.

Answer (score 2):

1) Add a line manager column to the calendar list

 
2) In SPD, update the line manager column in the calendar to the line manager of the leave request

 
3) Filter the view so Line Manager = [Me]